# Why doesn't giving kids more time work?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

So my child ran out of their alloted time on the computer today, so I went and gave them 4 more hours.  This is the parental controls where you select how much time to add, and you add your own (administrator) user name and password.

However, a couple hours later I was surprised to see that my child had logged out, because it had told them they were out of time.   But then somehow even though they had logged out, the main login window still showed them logged in, so I reboot the computer.

However this evening I was going to give them 15 minutes of time to print something, but after I enter my credentials, it no sooner has logged them in, then the window does the 3 dimensional "user switching" by itself, and now they are at the login window, and it is telling them they can log in again tomorrow.  I try to add 15 minutes again, and it does the same thing.  So I try 30 minutes, and they are logged in for about a minute and it logs them out again.

Why can't I give my kid more time on the computer?  They weren't trying to login during bedtime hours, they had only exceeded their weekend limit of 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It does the same for me, too, sometimes. Generally it solves itself. If it does not, try giving them the rest of the day and see if that logs them out.

Also, rebooting will log them out, for sure.